# jQuery UI tooltip position different in IE and chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, position, tooltip

I am observing different positioning behaviour while using jQuery UI tooltip widget in MSIE 11 and Chrome 49.

If the page with the widget is scrolled in MSIE the tooltip is displayed on the wrong position:

[image: Wrong tooltip position]

Please see the jsfiddle in MSIE to demonstrate the issue.

```
    $(".helpIcon").tooltip({
      hide: false,
      show: false,
      position: {
        my: "right top+3",
        at: "right bottom",
        using: function(position) {
          console.log(position);
          $(this).css(position);
        }
      }
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v9Lpxa05/3/

I am doing something unexpected? Or is there a hack I need to apply?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the tooltip widget.

For some reason IE skips the initial position calculation when the tooltip div is created, and first sets it when its displayed. However the position function makes an extra calculation if the `top` and `left` values are default, thus causing the different behaviour.

A quick and dirty workaround is to set the `top` and `left` properties to an initial 0 when calling `.position`:

```
var positionOriginal = $.fn.position;
$.fn.position = function(val) {
  if ( val ) {
    this.css("top", "0");
    this.css("left", "0");
  }
  return positionOriginal.call(this, val);
};
```

Use with caution! This solves the immediate problem, but hacks like this generally shouldn't go in production code. Behaviour might change in any future update

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/450uj66d/1/

Comment: All right. I will eventually file a bug report. For the time being I fixed it by specifying the position explicitly via CSS. See https://jsfiddle.net/450uj66d/2/ Thanks for the answer!